# Network Manager/OpenVPN Won't connect to PIA

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've got Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

Since installing an update about a week ago, I can not connect to PIA.  I used OpenVPN to connect, normally.

When I push connect, it doesn't even attempt to do anything.  It doesn't give a failed message or give the usual animation to let you know it's working on the request.  Nothing.

If I click on the gear menu in the top right and go to System Settings, then Networks, I can select the connection there and toggle the on/off switch and it will give me a successful "connected" message.  However, when I test my connection through http://www.ipleak.net it leaks everything (so, clearly it isn't actually connecting).

I've tried uninstalling and purging OpenVPN and Network Manager, but nothing changed.

Is this a known bug with the latest update?  If so, is there an easy way to revert Ubuntu, until this update is made stable?  If not, any ideas that might help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There seem to be some issues with the network manager.
Maybe this topic helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/892708/openvpn-loses-dns-after-suspend
It did for me.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm trying to find a solution myself.

Comment: // , I'm in the same boat. I can use their servers via OpenVPN, but that's about it.