# OpenVPN loses DNS after suspend

Tags: network-manager, suspend, dns, vpn, openvpn

On Ubuntu 16.04 I have Network Manager configured to automatically use an OpenVPN connection at system start-up. This works well.

However, when the machine resumes after being suspended, although the VPN reconnects, I am unable to browse (or ping) websites because host names cannot be resolved. For some reason DNS look-ups are failing.

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

This only started happening a couple of weeks ago, I'm not sure what has changed.

---

Output of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Output of `host -v www.apple.com` (before suspending):

```
Trying "www.apple.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41111
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 9, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.apple.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.apple.com.      1287    IN  CNAME   www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net. 1516 IN  CNAME   www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net. 1516 IN CNAME e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 20  IN  A   104.94.190.92

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n3dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n1dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n6dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  a0dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n4dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n5dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n0dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n7dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n2dsce9.akamaiedge.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a0dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  AAAA    2600:1480:e800::c0
n0dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   88.221.81.194
n1dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.157
n2dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   95.101.2.121
n3dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   95.101.79.79
n4dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.159
n5dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.164

Received 504 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 66 ms
Trying "e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60195
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 9, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net.    IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 20  IN  AAAA    2a02:26f0:60:186::1aca
e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 20  IN  AAAA    2a02:26f0:60:199::1aca

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n0dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n2dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n3dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  a0dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n4dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n1dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n5dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n6dsce9.akamaiedge.net.
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   1516    IN  NS  n7dsce9.akamaiedge.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a0dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  AAAA    2600:1480:e800::c0
n0dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   88.221.81.194
n1dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.157
n2dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   95.101.2.121
n3dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   95.101.79.79
n4dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.159
n5dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.164
n6dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.165
n7dsce9.akamaiedge.net. 1516    IN  A   23.62.100.166

Received 454 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 29 ms
Trying "e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44627
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net.    IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dsce9.akamaiedge.net.   600 IN  SOA n0dsce9.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1489520008 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 109 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 28 ms
```

Output of `host -v www.apple.com` (after suspending):

```
Trying "www.apple.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `host -v www.apple.com`. Show me the last command from before AND after suspend.

Comment: ps: does DNS continue to work after suspend if you DON'T use OpenVPN?

Comment: thanks heynnema, yes, DNS continues to work after suspending when not using OpenVPN

Comment: What happens if you restart `dnsmasq` after a suspend? Does it work then?

Comment: I couldn't work out how to restart `dnsmasq` but I found restarting `network-manager` would fix the problem _sometimes_ but not every time.

So I read through a few [bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager) regarding network-manager, DNS and suspend. One commenter [suggested downgrading](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1631241/comments/20) the network-manager package with `sudo apt install network-manager=1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4` and `sudo apt-mark hold network-manager` so I've tried that as a workaround and so far so good.

Comment: Good news! Write down what you did so you can undo it at a later date. Maybe it's already fixed in 16.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Tuesday (2017-04-18) my system updates included new versions of several DNS-related packages (including `dnsutils` and `dnsmasq-base`). Once these were installed the problem went away.